# Remove dividers from Preference List View

Tags: android, listview

Is there any way to remove the dividers in the list view that is automatically created when using a `PreferenceFragment`? Before when I used a `PreferenceActivity` I could access it using `getListView();` and then applying my customization. What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this using a custom style. First, in your `style.xml` file, create a new style for your `PreferencesActivity`:

```
<style name="PreferencesStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:listDivider">@null</item>
</style>
```

Second, add the theme to the `<activity>` tag for your `PreferencesActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
    android:name=".PreferencesActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_preferences"
    android:theme="@style/PreferencesStyle">
</activity>
```

The dividers in the list should now be invisible.

Comment: Plain and simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `ListView` in the `onCreateView()` method of your `PreferenceFragment`.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    ListView list = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    // you got a reference to the ListView now.
}
```